# Exact value of a sequence of coefficients.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Let $a_1=-1$ and $a_n=-1-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}a_j[n/j]$, where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. Is it always true that $a_n\in\{-1,0,1\}$?

These coefficients are determined by the formal equality $\chi_{(0,1)}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\rho(1/(nx))$, where $\rho(x)=x-[x]$, which is related to the characterization of the Riemann Hypothesis in terms of the approximation in $L^2(0,\infty)$ of the above characteristic function by the linear combinations of the sequence $\{\rho(1/(nx))\}_n$

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to start your studies of number theory from below, from arithmetic functions, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function (hint!), and not from Riemann Hypothesis?

Comment: Thank you for the "hint". I still don't see why this sequence is $-\mu(n)$, but probably this is also well-known. Regarding your question... by no means I was trying anything close to solving RH, just wanted to see whether I could place this as a homework to my first year Calculus students :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's identify your coefficients $a_j$:
Your equation can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\lfloor n/j\rfloor=-1,$$ since $\lfloor n/n\rfloor=1$
(I'll use the notation $\lfloor x\rfloor$ for the integer part of $x$, as it is more common nowadays than the $[x]$ used in my youth). For $n-1$ instead of $n$, this is
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_j\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor=-1,$$ but can also be written
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor=-1,$$ because $\lfloor (n-1)/n\rfloor=0$.
Subtraction of both equations gives
$$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j(\lfloor n/j\rfloor-\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor)=0.$$ Now it's easy to see that $\lfloor n/j\rfloor-\lfloor (n-1)/j\rfloor$ is $0$ if $n$ is not a multiple of $j$, and $1$ if it is. So our equation becomes $$\sum_{j|n}a_j=0.$$ This is exactly the equation satisfied by the Möbius function,
$$\sum_{j|n}\mu(j)=0,$$ just with the starting value $a_1=-1$ instead of $\mu(1)=1$. This means we have $a_j=-\mu(j)$ for all $j\ge1$.

Comment: Ah I misread I thought it was $a([n/j])$ instead of $a_j \times [n/j]$, one gives (minus) the Mertens function the other one gives $\mu$ :-)

Comment: Thanks again, this completely answers my question.